# Tradingview Widget Question: Embedding Multiple Symbols on Same Scale Comparasion

Tags: javascript, wordpress, embedding, tradingview-api

i am literally newbie to coding and facing a problem by embedding Tradingview on my wordpress website.

i want to add this chart : [CHART](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/EZn59q0h/?symbol=CRYPTOCAP%3AUSDT.D) to my website as it is, with all the other compared symbols.
(Sharing is on)

Iframe does not work.

[Tradingview provides some widgets:](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/)

but it does not show all the pairs, even i change the href on the code with my link.

I need help!

I asked chatgpt, and searched for 2 days on web: and nothing works.

This does not work either:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
<div id="tradingview_49079"></div>
<div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/chart/EZn59q0h/?symbol="BINANCE:BTCUSDT,BINANCE:ETHUSDT,BINANCE:ADAUSDT,BINANCE:BCHUSDT,BINANCE:DOGEUSDT,BINANCE:DOTUSDT,BINANCE:EOSUSDT,BINANCE:ETCUSDT,BINANCE:LINKUSDT,BINANCE:LTCUSDT,BINANCE:MATICUSDT,BINANCE:THETAUSDT,BINANCE:XLMUSDT,BINANCE:XMRUSDT,BINANCE:XRPUSDT,BINANCE:XTZUSDT" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span class="blue-text">Cryptocurrency Market Cap chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var symbolX = "BINANCE:BTCUSDT,BINANCE:ETHUSDT,BINANCE:ADAUSDT,BINANCE:BCHUSDT,BINANCE:DOGEUSDT,BINANCE:DOTUSDT,BINANCE:EOSUSDT,BINANCE:ETCUSDT,BINANCE:LINKUSDT,BINANCE:LTCUSDT,BINANCE:MATICUSDT,BINANCE:THETAUSDT,BINANCE:XLMUSDT,BINANCE:XMRUSDT,BINANCE:XRPUSDT,BINANCE:XTZUSDT"; // List of all the futures USDT pairs from Binance
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": false, // set to false to disable autosizing
  "symbols": [
    {
      "symbol": "CRYPTOCAP:USDT.D", // USDT.D for USDT Dominance
      "interval": "1", // change to your desired interval
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "dark", // set to "dark" for dark theme
      "style": "8", // change to your desired style number
      "locale": "en",
    },
    {
      "symbol": symbolX, // Use the variable "symbolX" to include all the desired futures USDT pairs from Binance
      "interval": "1", // change to your desired interval
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "dark", // set to "dark" for dark theme
      "style": "8", // change to your desired style number
      "locale": "en",
    }
  ],
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "hide_legend": true,
  "withdateranges": true,
  "hide_side_toolbar": false,
  "show_popup_button": true,
  "popup_width": "960",
  "popup_height": "640",
  "container_id": "tradingview_49079"
}
  );
  </script>

</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Please help!